# Service URL for Notification-Only Teams Bot

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am working on a notification only teams bot limited to members of a single azure ad tenant. Based on this documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-context - the serviceUrl could change.

Since the bot would hardly ever receive a request, how do I manage the serviceUrl? What could cause the serviceUrl to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service URL are unique to region, not tenant.

You can cache the team and user details when bot is added to a team in [conversation update bot event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition). You could use it later to send messages.

Comment: Thanks. By region do you mean the location of the bot deployment, or the location of the tenant?

Comment: A tenant can have multiple location. it should be bot.