# Do all users in the same tenant share serviceUrl for MS Teams Bot?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm building a MS Teams bot and have a question about the `serviceUrl`.
For some context, our bot app will be installed in our customers' teams and we are wondering if users in the same tenant will share the same `serviceUrl`. We are aware that this url changes from time to time but trying to figure out at what resource level we need to cache this value.

Would be ideal if I can keep track of a single `serviceUrl` for my bot but wondering if the url could vary from tenant to tenant, or even, user to user.
Figuring this serviceUrl is an important piece to our implementation because 1) we want to be able to get the teams roster 2) we want to be able to send proactive messages to a user that has never messaged us before.

Please let me know if there is anything I could clarify and thank you so much for your help!

This was the documentation for Teams Roster that we were looking at that explains the `serviceUrl`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=json#fetching-the-roster-or-user-profile

Comment: Yes, within the same tenant service URL will be same for all users across the tenant level. You don't need to keep track of service URL, if your Bot will get installed in some other tenant, service URL will be changed. Why you are keeping track of service URL?

Comment: Hi Trinetra! Thank you so much for the clarification. We wanted to keep track of the serviceUrl so that we can send proactive messages to users who hasnt messaged us before. To do this I believe we need the most up-to-date serviceUrl? If I understand correctly, the serviceUrl changes very rarely but it does change. We will have multiple tenants communicating with our bot as well.

Comment: So depending on which region the tenant info is stored, we might have different serviceUrl for some of them. But if there is an api we can use to get that, please let us know! That would be the best. We are using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 for our messaging

Comment: Yes, That is the correct one API.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Thanks for confirming and help me out!

Comment: The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764564/service-url-for-notification-only-teams-bot seems to say that a tenant can have multiple regions and that service URLs are unique to a region. That contradicts Trinetra-MSFT's comment above that says there is only one service URL per tenant.  Am I interpreting something? If so, which answer is correct?

Comment: @GabrielDeal, serviceURL changes as per region.